# add multiple times from a mysql time field in php

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a table with the following structure and i want to get the sum of all the times for a certain `album_id` & `disc`. I found this http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10326769-RESOLVED-time-help and it looked somewhat good (the first snippet of code in the first answer), but I cant figure out how to work it ith mysql...

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tracks` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artist_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `album_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `disc` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `track_no` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `length` time NOT NULL,
  `size` decimal(20,1) NOT NULL,
  `plays` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `artist_id` (`artist_id`,`album_id`,`disc`,`track_no`,`title`)
) ;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm a noob!!!

Comment: I don't get it, what do you want to sum?

Comment: the length field fro a certain album + disc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will do.

```
SELECT album_id, disc, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(length))) AS formatTime
FROM tracks
GROUP BY album_id, disc
HAVING album_id=id AND disc=disc
```

Alternative for only a certain album and disc:

```
SELECT album_id, disc, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(length))) AS formatTime
FROM tracks
WHERE album_id=id AND disc=disc
```

Comment: I already tried it with the SUM method in mysql and it doesn't wrk, it returns 968. but thats not a time.

Comment: I'm quite sure that's a time. How about trying to convert it into other units?

Comment: Sorry I meant it doesn't come out formatted right. it should be 10:08.

Comment: Maybe you mean this. See my answer.

Comment: My bad, you have to use CONCAT() in MySQL to concatenate strings. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: i found it, you were missing a closing ) for the first CONCAT! now its printing 7:18, and the total time should be 10:08.

Comment: Oops, sorry!! Well, I edited my answer again with a simple function call. What's the output now?

Comment: the output now is 4:18 lol going down in time :D this is turning out to be a lil harder than expected.

Comment: you were missing WHERE `album_id="'.$album_id.'" AND disc="'.$disc.'"` in your statement, so i added it and we are back to 7:18 lol

Comment: It's a bit harder, indeed. I had to find a workaround. Modify your query and tell me the output. And no, I didn't miss the WHERE statement, this query will return the full list of albums and discs. In case you want to filter them out, use the HAVING statement instead.

Comment: `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(length)))` now outputs 4:18

Comment: Are you sure that's not the correct time? Did you filter out the result using the HAVING statement?

Comment: yes i tried with a WHERE and a HAVING statement, same results, 4:18. The 2 times in the database it should add up as it currently sits are 4:38 & 5:30 for a total of 10:08.

Comment: You could, alternately, remove the GROUP BY...HAVING statement and replace it with a WHERE statement so only the album and disc you want will be displayed.

Comment: oh wait it totally worked before with the last way you had it. `$query = 'SELECT album_id, disc, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(length))) AS length FROM tracks GROUP BY album_id, disc HAVING album_id="'.$album_id.'" AND disc="'.$disc.'"';` I forgot that the other song was a demo one i did for disc 2 lmao. I have been at it all day. time to take a break.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is the album we want
$album = 24;

//grab all the track lengths and plays from our album
$query = '
SELECT length, plays
FROM tracks
WHERE album_id = "'.$album.'";

//do our mysql query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//now for every result do somthing like add the length of the songs or play count
$length = null;
$plays = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $length = $length + $row["length"];
  $pays = $plays + $row["plays"];
}

//echo data to user
echo 'The total lenth of this albums is:'.$length.'mins';
echo 'this ablum as been played:'.$plays.'times';
```

Comment: why not just do a `SUM()` in SQL!?